# Windows Vim overwrites WSL file mode

Tags: microsoft-windows, linux, wsl

I'm using gVim on Windows to edit files in WSL2 Ubuntu via the [`\\wsl$`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/) mapping. When I `:write` in Vim, it overwrites the linux file mode/permissions with `644`/`-rw-r--r--`, no matter what the mode was to begin with.
Other editors (Notepad, Notepad++) don't do this, so I know it can't just be an issue with `umask` or something.

```
$ pwd
/home/me/testf
$ ls -lh
total 4.0K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me me  0 Mar 17 11:06 execfile.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me  0 Mar 17 11:18 textfile.txt

$ #write both files in Notepad or Notepad++, as \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\me\testf\*file.txt
$ ls -lh
total 4.0K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 18 Mar 17 11:18 execfile.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me  5 Mar 17 11:18 textfile.txt

$ #write both files in Windows Vim, as \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\me\testf\*file.txt
$ ls -lh
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 19 Mar 17 11:19 execfile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  5 Mar 17 11:19 textfile.txt
```

Is there some way to configure Vim to change this behavior? Or does it need a patch?

Vim 8.2.373;
Ubuntu 20.04.2 (WSL2);
Windows 10 20H2